# change content outside and inside brackets with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

i need to  change this  line:   `count(id)`

to line like this `count(tableName.`id`)`

i try to do this with preg match and replace like this:

```
    $a = "count(id)";
    $regex = "/\w{3,}+\W/";
    $dd = preg_match("/\(.*?\)/", $a, $matches);
    $group = $matches[0];

    if (preg_match($regex, $a)) {

    $c = preg_replace("$group", "(table.`$group`)", $a);

    var_dump($c);

    }
```

output that i got is :  `count((table.`(id)`))` its outputting me extra brackets . i know the problem but i can't find solution because my regex knowledge not so good.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "count(id)";
$regex = "/\w{3,}+\W/";
$dd = preg_match("/\((.*?)\)/", $a, $matches);

$group = $matches[1]; // <-- you'll get error if the above regex doesn't match!

if (preg_match($regex, $a)) {
    $c = preg_replace("/$group/", "table.$group", $a);
}
```

Comment: actually i find write pattern by myself, but yours is same )) yes thanks.